# Creating an Array that uses a Varargs Struct with function Pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, function-pointers, variadic-functions

I'm currently learning about Varargs and now sitting in front of the Problem that I can't bring them in an Array and call them with e.g. a `for`-Loop.
Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<typename... T>
struct DataStructure
{
};

template<typename T, typename ... Rest>
struct DataStructure<T, Rest ...>
{
    DataStructure(const T& first, const Rest& ... rest)
        : first(first)
        , rest(rest...)
    {}

    T first;
    DataStructure<Rest ... > rest;
};

void foo()
{
    printf("Hello from foo\n");
}

void foo2()
{
    printf("Hello from foo2\n");
}

int main()
{
    DataStructure<std::function<void()>, int, int> data(&foo, 1, 2);
    DataStructure<std::function<void()>, int, int> data2(foo2, 3, 4);

    data.first();
    data2.first();
    return 0;
}
```

My Problem lays in getting those `DataStructure` into an Array which I then call from an `for`-Loop. While the above Code works fine, does it not anymore if I try to bring them into an Array like I usually could do with a normal Struct like:

```
const DataStructure tempArray[]
{
DataStructure<std::function<void()>, int, int> data(&foo, 1, 2),
DataStructure<std::function<void()>, int, int> data2(&foo2, 3, 4),
};

int main()
{
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        tempArray[i].first;
    }
}
```

Appreciated for any advice & help

Also does someone have an explanation why for my above Varargs Struct it doesn't matter if I use the `&` when calling it in my Main? I tested both and both seems to work just fine.

Edit for further explaination:
I try to build a struct that has no set number of members. My Code should easy the Problem that I have, that some Functions I call with the Pointer only take 2 values, while some have up to 7 values.
So I could write a Member for every of those new added values but that would get quite messy in future update handling, so I want to make it not a set number, but for each function decide myself how many varaibles I pass to the function. Hence why I use a function pointer in first place to call the function in this `for`-Loop easily when I have all my functions in an Array to have easier overview.
Hope that helps to explain why I'm trying to solve it like I do now, appreciated for any better way of doing that.

Comment: *"it doesn't matter if I use the `&`"* functions (as C-array) decays to pointers implicitly in some contexts.

Comment: Please be careful, [variadic functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic) (like `printf`) and variadic templates (also known as [parameter packs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)) are two different things.

Comment: It seems you try to reimplement [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple). which have `std::apply` and folding expression to iterate over its members.

Comment: *"getting those DataStructure into an Array which I then call from an for-Loop..."* - Can you specify what do you mean by that? Seems to work fine for me: https://godbolt.org/z/Y8bsrGcMM

Comment: `While the above Code works fine, does it not anymore if I try to bring them into` Please post the code that does not work. We do not know what did you do to break it.

Comment: Edited the Code to what I was supposted to send, sorry for the confusion, I will add some more specification to my Question as well

Comment: In what way does your code not work? Is there a compile error? Would you mind sharing it?

Comment: @Useless basically I can't call my `tempArray[i].first`, it throws two errors from *invalid use of template-name ‘DataStructure’ without an argument list* in the row `const DataStructure tempArray[]` to *error: ‘tempArray’ was not declared in this scope tempArray[i].first;*

Comment: Well, `DataStructure` isn't the name of a type. It's the name of a template. `DataStructure<std::function<void()>, int, int>` _is_ the name of a type, and you could potentially declare an array of them. Have you tried just writing it out that way?

Comment: @Useless Yes, but then I have basically made the effort of the variadic template for nothing, since it will make me need to create an Array for any different type of `DataStructure` I have. So i could then also create a Struct for any of them and would potentially have the same outcome sadly

Comment: You've only shown one instantiation of your template anyway, so it's really unclear how you want to use this. If you want to capture a variable number of function arguments you can bind them all up inside your existing `std::function`, possibly using a lambda - but you're not using them at all now and I can't tell if that's what you want to do with them.

Comment: @Useless tried to explain a bit further in my Edit, basically trying to have an Array of a variable sized struct and that struct should contain my function pointer and their arguments in one array member. Sorry my english is not so well, it's hard for me to explain properly

Comment: @Deto24 it's not really matter that your english is not good, but you should post [mcve] that contains what you want **by code**.

Comment: I *think* that `std::function` already does everything you need, but I can't really tell because you haven't said whether the `Rest...` parameters are ever used for anything. Are they supposed to be the function parameters? Do you always know them in advance, so you never need to pass anything when calling `first()`?

Comment: composition of  `std::tuple` bound `std::function`s?! Is there a chance you are trying to implement the observer pattern (in which case `boost::signals2` is at large)?

Comment: @Useless yes I found a solution today. I didn't use the `std::function` properly since it kept all I need. Basically making me use variadic functions wrong. I couldn't test it fully yet, but if wanted can post my solution later tomorrow